# Не срабатывает PreUpdate в Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть вот такой класс:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity    
class MyEntity {

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_WRITE)
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String birthPlace;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
        updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Написал тест таким образом:

```
String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

repository.save(new MyEntity().setId(id));
MyEntity savedEntity = repository.getOne(id);

assertNotNull(savedEntity.getCreatedAt());
assertNotNull(savedEntity.getUpdatedAt());
assertEquals(savedEntity.getCreatedAt(), savedEntity.getUpdatedAt());

Thread.sleep(100);
savedEntity = repository.save(repository.getOne(id).setBirthPlace("Moscow"));
assertNotNull(savedEntity.getCreatedAt());
assertNotNull(savedEntity.getUpdatedAt());
assertNotEquals(savedEntity.getCreatedAt(), savedEntity.getUpdatedAt());
```

В тесте выше `repository` - это `JpaRepository`. Проблема в том, что хук на `PrePersist` работает, а на `PreUpdate` не срабатывает. Не понимаю почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты включишь логгирование SQL, то увидишь, что `UPDATE`-запрос не выполняется, поскольку никаких изменений в объекте `savedEntity` нет. Соответственно, `@PreUpdate`-хук тоже не вызывается.

Перед сохранением изменений Hibernate/JPA получает текущее состояние объекта из БД и сравнивает с сохраняемым объектом. Если они идентичны, то `UPDATE`-запрос не будет выполнен.

Перед вызовом `savedEntity = repository.save(repository.getOne(id));` нужно изменить значение какого-либо свойства объекта `savedEntity`, тогда и запрос будет выполнен, и хук сработает.

Comment: Согласен, пример неудачный. Обновил.

Comment: Но вы были правы в общем случае. Я совсем забыл сделать `repository.flush()`. После него все заработало.